# Django 1.7 / 1.8 Cannot resolve keyword

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to Django and I am having a little trouble. I am following this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/ . Here is my model for testing :

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.TextField(max_length=200)

class Deptcontacts(models.Model):
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    contact_name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    contact_phone = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Ok, when I try to use :

```
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(department__dept_name='PublicWorks')
```

or :

```
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(department__dept_name__contains='Pub')
```

I get the following error :

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'department' into field. Choices are: contact_name, contact_phone, dept, dept_id, id

Anyone know why? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(dept__dept_name__contains='Pub')
```

Comment: I just posted my answer right when you did Othman  . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I see where I was making my boo boo.

I have

```
class Department(models.Model):
    dept_name = models.TextField(max_length=200)

class Deptcontacts(models.Model):
    dept = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    contact_name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    contact_phone = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

And this 
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(department__dept_name__contains='Pub')

Should be 
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(dept__dept_name__contains='Pub')

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because there is **no field `department` in your model `Department`**.

To use `.filter(**kwargs)` on a queryset, `kwargs` should be model fields.

You need to do something like:

```
Deptcontacts.objects.filter(dept__dept_name='PublicWorks') # use model field 'dept' 

Deptcontacts.objects.filter(dept__dept_name__contains='Pub') # use model field 'dept'
```